# Why my variable is unsafe in erlang try?

Tags: exception, erlang

I'm new in Erlang. I have problem with this code below:

```
try
    {ok, [Card]} = io:fread("Input card number: ","~d")
    catch
      error:K -> (Card=0);
      exit:K -> (Card=0);
      throw:K -> (Card=0)
    end,
```

I don't know why 'variable 'Card' unsafe in 'try'. What can I do about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code like yours would work in a `case` expression, but for a `try`, this is an exception to the variable binding rules in Erlang.  From [the reference manual](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id80120):

> For the try expression introduced in Erlang 5.4/OTP R10B, variable scoping is limited so that variables bound in the expression are always 'unsafe' outside the expression. This is to be improved.

You could write your code like this:

```
Card =
  try
    {ok, [C]} = io:fread("Input card number: ","~d"),
    C
  catch
    error:K -> 0;
    exit:K -> 0;
    throw:K -> 0
  end,
```